# Pattern matching 'Some and None' does not match the float in float option?

Tags: ocaml, typeerror

I am trying to match the float returned from `List.Assoc.find` (float option).

I'm using pattern-matching but it does not seem to work.

```
let evalVar (_x: string) (_q:envQueue): float  = 
    match List.Assoc.find _q _x with
        Some(s) -> s
        | None -> 0.0
```

I get this error:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a option
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
         equal:(string -> string -> bool) -> float option
```

Comment: Just a note: prefixing an identifier with an underscore suppresses warnings about unused names. It should not be used for names that are not unused, since then the warning, and this signifier that it is intentional, loses its purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `List.Assoc.find` is :

```
utop # List.Assoc.find;;
- : ('a, 'b) List.Assoc.t -> equal:('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a -> 'b option =
<fun>
```

`List.Assoc.find` expects the `equal` parameter which is a function.

Ocaml interprets the code  `List.Assoc.find _q _x` as :

- `_q` : is the first parameter, so its type is `('a, 'b) List.Assoc.t`.
- Since `equal` is not mentionned, `_x` is the 3rd parameter of the signature hereabove, therefore it is a typed as a string (this is specified by the type constraint of the function `evalVar`).

Herebelow is an example of `List.Assoc.find`:

```
utop # List.Assoc.find [("a",1);("b",2)] ~equal:(fun  _a _b -> _a=_b) "a";;
- : int option = Some 1
```